# App flutter crash after login to firebase_authentification

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, dart

I've been trying to run my flutter project, but when I login, I have a lot of errors and I can't resolve them I have looked at several posts and made several modifications but nothing works ... Here is my error message:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone de Robin in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 7PY6666GWP
Xcode build done.                                           235,1s
(lldb) 2021-10-22 12:24:53.026762+0200 Runner[37329:4704419] 8.8.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.8.8.0 started
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '381192590305'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: aucune autorisation « aps-environment » valide détectée pour l’application
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
[] nw_hash_table_apply called with null table
[] nw_hash_table_apply called with null table, dumping backtrace:
        [arm64] libnetcore-2736.12.1
    0   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001864832f0 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 116
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000185c61820 nw_hash_table_apply + 2676
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001861ac450 EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 6030416
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000186188a9c EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 5884572
    4   CFNetwork                           0x000000018599952c _CFURLStorageSessionCopyIdentifier + 14364
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000185d7beb8 EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 1638072
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184ce12ec 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 406252
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184ce22f0 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 410352
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184cbf154 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 266580
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184cc776c 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 300908
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de98ef38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de98eaa4 start_wqthread + 8
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:63353/2UM89wqPPa8=/ws
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
Writing analzed variants.
Writing analzed variants.
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023130] Configuration not found. Using default configuration
[] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_hash_table_apply called with null table"
[] nw_hash_table_apply called with null table, dumping backtrace:
        [arm64] libnetcore-2736.12.1
    0   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001864832f0 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 116
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000185c61820 nw_hash_table_apply + 2676
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001861ac450 EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 6030416
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000186188a9c EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 5884572
    4   CFNetwork                           0x000000018599952c _CFURLStorageSessionCopyIdentifier + 14364
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000185d7beb8 EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 1638072
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184ce12ec 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 406252
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184ce22f0 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 410352
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184cbf154 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 266580
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000184cc776c 5D722AFC-FB8C-3769-BF66-167BB94A6133 + 300908
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de98ef38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de98eaa4 start_wqthread + 8
GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 1395, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 226b696e 64223a20 22696465 ... 33363030 220a7d0a }, error (null)
GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 683, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 226b696e 64223a20 22696465 ... 7d0a2020 5d0a7d0a }, error (null)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'To use location in iOS8 and above you need to define either NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in the app bundle's Info.plist file'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185015cac 0x19c084758 0x185068d14 0x104010a6c 0x10401062c 0x10ac2ed60 0x10a94007c 0x10ac49370 0x10abe34d4 0x10abe5cfc 0x185029fdc 0x184fb4348 0x184faefdc 0x184f8eeb4 0x184fa1d8c 0x19f0ae9a0 0x1877d7018 0x18756b29c 0x1020ff19c 0x103cf0190)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001be566a48 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1be566a48 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1be566a64               ; <+36>
    0x1be566a4c <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1be566a50 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1be566a54 <+20>: bl     0x1be5626d0               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I don't know if is Firebase/Analytics or Firebase/Messaging who create this error but it's problematic..

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashed due to this error - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'To use location in iOS8 and above you need to define either NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in the app bundle's Info.plist file'`

You should update your iOS Project's info.plist in xcode with proper keys as mentioned in the exception message